# Does not working switch-case with unordered_map and char*

Tags: c++, switch-statement, embedded, unordered-map

I'm writing the code for MCU, but debugging the algorithm on PC. The variable `line` contains a command received from computer.

Command types:

- "LD D1 ON" means that need to turn on diode D1;
- "G1 OM ST" means that engine #1 should work in first mode;
- etc.

There will be about one hundred commands, so I decided to use `unordered_map` with `switch-case` instead of `strcmp()` with lots of `if-else` blocks (I think this will work faster on MCU).

The problem is this: after the first `switch-case` it's all OK, displaying LD or G1 or G2. **But,** the second `switch-case` doesn't work!

If I write `cout << parameter << value << endl` before `switch(Diodes[parameter])`, I see the right result, but I can't understand why the 2<sup>nd</sup> switch doesn't want to work. If I include `<string>` and, instead of `char*`, use `string`, it works - but I don't want to include this library, because MCU has a small amount of memory and, in the future, more functionality will be added.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <unordered_map>

#define LD 0
#define G1 1
#define G2 2

#define D1 1
#define D2 2
#define D3 3

using namespace std;

unordered_map<char*, int> Devices = {
    {"LD", LD},
    {"G1", G1},
    {"G2", G2}
};

unordered_map<char*, int> Diodes = {
    {"D1", D1},
    {"D2", D2},
    {"D3", D3}
};

void chooseDiode(char *, char *);

int main() {
    char line[] = "LD D1 ON\r";

    char *device = strtok(line," \n\r");

    switch(Devices[device]){
        case LD:{
            cout << device << endl;
            chooseDiode(strtok(NULL, " \n\r"),strtok(NULL, " \n\r"));
            break;
        }
        case G1: {
            cout << device << endl;
            break;
        }
        case G2: {
            cout << device << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void chooseDiode(char *parameter, char *value){
    switch(Diodes[parameter]){
        case D1: {
            cout << parameter << value << endl;
            break;
        }
        case D2: {
            cout << parameter << value << endl;
            break;
        }
        case D3: {
            cout << parameter << value << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are storing raw pointers as keys in your unordered map.  These are NOT being used as strings by the hash function.  You must define a custom hash function to hash the _string data_, otherwise it's just hashing the _pointer value_.

Comment: Unrelated, but the order of evaluation of the arguments in the `chooseDiode` call is unspecified, so those two `strtok` may not be called in that order.

Comment: make your life easy, use std::string instead of char* in the unordered_map.

Comment: I would recommend abandoning the unordered map approach altogether.  What is wrong with just testing the first character of a command and then taking appropriate action?  You can use a switch for this.  This is especially useful for things like `Gx` where `x` is a digit but the overall logic should be similar for all occurrances of that type of command.